# Can we use for loop in ParamGridBuilder of pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

The below code is to add the parameters to paramGridBuilder without any loops in pyspark.

```py
from pyspark.ml.tuning import ParamGridBuilder
paramGrid = ParamGridBuilder()\
        .addGrid(lr.regParam, [0.1, 0.01]) \
        .addGrid(lr.fitIntercept, [False, True])\
        .addGrid(lr.elasticNetParam, [0.0, 0.5, 1.0])\
        .build()
```

I have a dictionary like this

```py
 dict =   {lr.regParam : [0.1,0.01],lr.fitIntercept:[False,True],lr.elasticNetParam:[0.0,0.5,1.0]
```

Can we use a loop to build the ParamgridBuilder and will it work?

```py
for k,v in dict.items():
    paramGrid = ParamGridBuilder().addGrid(k,v).build()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the reduce function :

```py
from functools import reduce
paramGrid  = reduce(
    lambda a,b: a.addGrid(*b),
    dict.items(),
    ParamGridBuilder(),
).build()
```

or with a for loop

```py
paramGrid = ParamGridBuilder()
for k,v in dict.items():
    paramGrid = paramGrid.addGrid(k,v)
paramGrid = paramGrid.build()
```